# Curve_fitting data (I'm close to the params values, but curve_fit says optimal parameters not found)

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit the data in [this file](http://www.filedropper.com/aluminio33920umaire) with `curve_fit` from scipy in Python. The file contains data points of temperature vs time in celsius and milliseconds. I convert them to kelvin and seconds:

```
thefile = open("aluminio_33920um_aire.txt", "r")
data = np.loadtxt(thefile, delimiter='\t', skiprows=1)
Temp = data[:, 0] + 273.15  #kelvin
Time = data[:, 1]*1e-3  #secs
thefile.close()
```

I define a couple of functions to be fitted:

```
def newton(t, a, b, tau):
    return a + b * np.exp(-t/tau)

def dulong(t, ta, dift, f, n):
    return ta + (dift + (n-1)*t/f)**(1/(1-n))
```

newton's fitting works perfectly. But dulong does not. I have plotted several values for the parameters of duolong to see which values draw a line that more or less fits the data, and I found the values given here:

```
poptd, pcovd = curve_fit(dulong, Time, Temp, p0=[295, 0.155, 6000, 1.38], sigma=[1]*len(Temp), absolute_sigma=True)
```

However, passing these values `p0` to curve_fit does not help since I get the error

```
RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 1000.
```

Don't know how to improve since the initial guess of my parameters is a really good guess. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dulong function is highly sensitive to changes in n because of its `n^n` dependancy. You might want set bounds for it or even keep it as a constant if thats good enough for you.

Also, if you are dealing with sufficient small timescales you could consider using a approximating function. If not, try to take the logarithm of your temp data and fit the logarithm of the dulong function. This can be useful if the algorithm takes steps too big when variating n.

For debugging purposes you can add a line to your function which prints the parameters passed, that way you will be able to see which parameter is varied by how much and you can work from there.
As another measure you can take a look at the minimize function from scipy.optimize, there you will be able to specify more options like solving algorithm and stepwidth to be taken and you can also pass the jacobian to further improve efficiency.

Comment: As Wenzel said, the `n` parameter is the issue here. If you fix it to 1.38, the `curve_fit` function will return the fits: `3.11e+02  1.64e-01  5.03e+03` for `ta, dift, f`.

Answer (score 2):

When I call `curve_fit` using the `dulong` function I get the following warning:

> `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power`

This suggests that, as `curve_fit` tests various values of the parameters, evaluation of `dulong` requires computation of the form `(negative real)**(real)`, which results in a complex number. Hence, the optimization procedure fails.

One approach is to restrict the search space of your parameters so that this issue does not occur. Without knowing the physical meaning of the parameters, I can see that, as long as `n` is greater than `1` and all other parameters are non-negative, `dulong` will return only real numbers.

Calling `curve_fit` with a `bounds` option as described above has no problem finding the optimal parameters.

```
poptd, pcovd = curve_fit(dulong, Time, Temp, p0=[295, 0.155, 6000, 1.38], sigma=[1]*len(Temp), absolute_sigma=True,
                        bounds = ([0,0,0,1],[1000,1,10000,10]))

print(poptd)
```

> `[  304.5965     0.0857  9999.1743     1.5099]`

Here's the plot of the fit

[image]

Comment: Hello, I found this very helpful. However there is one problem, the third parameter corresponding to f=9999 has associated with it a HUGE error: sqrt(pcovd[2:2]). Do you know how to diminish this error?

Comment: @VladimirVargas I am not really sure how this "error" should be interpreted (i.e., does a large value means a "bad" fit?), let alone diminish it. However, I also notice that if we restrict the search space for `f` so that optimization results in a value close to the initial guess (`6000`), which you consider as "good", the corresponding error is also large.

Comment: If I change my sigma argument to have 0.01, then I get that the error is much smaller than the value of f.

Answer (score 0):

Since i can't post comments yet, i will instead post another answer as reply to your comment: The big error from the third parameter is likely due to the algorithm not being allowed to assign it a value above 10000. Adjust your bounds and it should work.

Comment: I'm using `param_bounds = np.array([[250,350], [0.12, 0.13], [6000, 80000], [1.3, 1.5]]).T` with
`poptd, pcovd = curve_fit(dulong, Time, Temp, p0=[295, 0.125, 6000, 1.38], sigma=[1]*len(Temp), absolute_sigma=True, bounds=param_bounds)
` and still get a huge error.

Comment: more than 100%, f is 7.00099861e+03 and sqrt(pcovd[2,2]) is 1.06431341e+04. I noticed that if I put a much lower value in sigma, e.g. 0.01, then the error goes to 1.06431902e+02, which is acceptable.